# Show value of combobox(item)

Tags: c#, combobox

I have made a own class called ComboBoxItem

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string _value;
    public string _text;

    public ComboBoxItem(string val, string text)
    {
        _value = val;
        _text = text;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _text;
    }
}
```

I put in a combobox some text with values in this way:

```
busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015503", "New Bridge Street-St Dominics");
comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops);
busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015552", "Bothal Street (N-Bound), Byker ");
comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops);
```

Now I like if I click on an item and click on a button a messagebox appears show the value of the selected item.

But the problem is the combobox can only show the text like "New Bridge Street..." because only the text is in my combobox and I like to show its value..

something like this:

```
Messagebox.show(combobox.selectedCombboxItem.Value);
```

What do I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: How can I associat a value to a text in a combobox?

Comment: you are right, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combobox will return an object which you will need to cast to `ComboBoxItem` in order to access the `Value`.

```
Messagebox.show(((ComboBoxItem)combobox.SelectedItem).Value);
```

Comment: The correct one, assuming we are talking about winforms should be Messagebox.show(((ComboBoxItem)combobox.SelectedItem).Value); I just used selectedCombboxItem since that was what you used in your question.

Answer (score 1):

selectedCombboxItem returns an object, `MessageBox.Show()` will be calling `ToString()`.

you need to cast the selectedCombboxItem to your own type

```
Messagebox.show(((ComboBoxItem)combobox.selectedCombboxItem).Value);
```